# Ubuntu Server 20.04 Removes RTL8125 driver after certain upgrades, how to prevent this?

Tags: networking, drivers, upgrade, kernel, realtek

Apologies if this has been answered already somewhere, I was having trouble sorting this issue out.

I have an MSI X570 MEG Unify motherboard with 2 NICs, one of which is a 2.5Gbps Realtek RTL8125 Ethernet port. I am able to successfully install the driver both using the driver from Realtek's site, as well as the DKMS package here:

https://github.com/awesometic/realtek-r8125-dkms

It is my understanding that the DKMS package ***should*** prevent removal of the driver during kernel upgrades, but I have found that the driver is still sometimes removed after an upgrade. I would prefer to use this port for the additional speed, but it is very unreliable as it stands now, as I do not always have physical access to this machine, and losing connectivity after upgrade is unacceptable. Is there someway I can tell ubuntu not to touch this driver when I issue apt upgrade commands?

Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Edit: Per chili555's request, the make.log can be found here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/x7CbjqW4r6/

Edit2: output of dkms status '''realtek-r8125, 9.006.04, 5.4.0-81-generic, x86_64: installed''' output of modprobe and dmesg was blank. I should mention that I already reinstalled the dkms module from the github link before I posted the question, sorry if that caused confusion. The driver is currently working, the issue I am trying to avoid is losing the driver when I issue the apt upgrade command.

Comment: If it did not upgrade (i.e. sucessfully compile), then the reason can be found in the make.log. It will be somewhere in /var/lib/dkms/. Please find it and post it here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: The log can be found here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/x7CbjqW4r6/

Comment: It appears to have compiled correctly. Please show us: `sudo dkms status` and also: `sudo modprobe r8125 && sudo dmesg | grep r8125` Please paste as above.

Comment: output of dkms status '''realtek-r8125, 9.006.04, 5.4.0-81-generic, x86_64: installed''' output of modprobe and dmesg was blank. I should mention that I already reinstalled the dkms module from the github link before I posted the question, sorry if that caused confusion. The driver is currently working, the issue I am trying to avoid is losing the driver when I issue the apt upgrade command.